# Как перевести round() с Паскаля на С++ и какие для этого нужны библиотеки?

Tags: c++, pascal

У меня есть код на паскале:

```
l := round(sqrt(i));
```

Как эту строчку кода перевести на С++? И какие библиотеки для этого надо?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для перевода на C++ надо убрать двоеточие

```
l=round(sqrt(i));
```

Необходимые функции находятся в [`math.h`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/)

Comment: `round` с 0.5 одинаково работает работает в обоих случаях?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, а почему нет? :) это ж round

Comment: Ну там Bankers Rounding вот это все

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, не знаю что это :)

Comment: Типа .5 округляется к четной стороне в случае Bankers

Comment: я думаю ,5 это настолько граничный случай, что лучше добавить/отнять эпсилон и не думать. Учесть точность вычислений.

Comment: @pavel вы просто не буквоед )

Comment: http://ideone.com/BnadNk http://ideone.com/pPEoRl в С я не вижу Bankers Rounding

Comment: @VladimirGamalian что такое `чётная сторона`? А помимо убирания двоеточия нужно ещё и `++` убрать :)

Comment: @alexolut округление ,5 проиходит к числу, которое делится на 2. `0.5 ->0 1.5->2`

Comment: интересно, знал ли автор об этой особенности округления)

Comment: @pavel т.е. `0.5 -> 0`, а `1.5 -> 2`? Это где такое востребовано?

Comment: http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/round.html фрипаскаль говорит, что юзает такой раундинг

Comment: @alexolut в паскале например http://ideone.com/BnadNk. Исторически сложилось несколько вариантов https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding

Comment: а ещё в С `double round (double)`  а в паскале `int round(double)`. Что приводит к интересным результатам типо -0, ну и банально не в тот тип не положишь.

Comment: @pavel или какой-нибудь `round(MAX_INT + 1.)`.

Comment: @alexolut востребовано в финансах, чтобы не было статистической склонности к округлению в большую или меньшую сторону.